# How to automatically append the txt contents of the X11 clipboard to the end of a Linux command line

Tags: shell, x11

:)

I use Linux Mint.

Each day I run a BASH script, that is appended with a new web link.

The script looks like this:
./analyse http://www.the-daily-variable-web-link-goes-here.com

Each day after I copy the link using a mouse, it would be nice to be able to simply double click a BASH script that would automatically pull the contents of the X11 (primary) clipboard (containing the web link) onto the end of the ./analyse command (command line).

I have xsel installed (I have been unable to install xclip).

Unable to figure this one out.

Any help, please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
#!/bin/sh
./analyse `xsel -o`
```

Comment: Thanks Erik :) I think the '-o' command works with xclip (from my researches?) but I just tried it with xsel and it's not, apparently working. I've been unable to get xclip installed (some sort of dependency error I cannot figure out)

Comment: Hi Erik :) Your right. xsel -o is valid and works. If I copy the link with my mouse and then run $ xsel -o it prints the link to the left of the command line $, but it's not going onto the script when I run ./analyse `'xsel -o'` !

Comment: Note that it is backticks (same as quoting code here) not citation marks ('). Can also be written as `./analyse $(xsel -o)`

Comment: What I had to do was the following : 'VAR=$(xsel -o) && echo $VAR'. I then called '$VAR' within the script. Works a dream. Does not answer my question as laid out though works a dream! :) Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Thanks Erik. Again U are right ! :) :) With the back ticks it works a dream. I had been using single quotes. Thank you very much for your help. Problem SOLVED